# Бинарный массив в изображение

Tags: vba

Доброго времени суток в VBS из коробки есть метод преобразующий иконку в бинарное представление.
Не подскажите как произвести обратное преобразование ил бинарного вида в изображение?

Comment: В тексте - `VBS`, метка - `VBA`. Где правда?

Comment: Укажите точно, какой метод имеется в виду (желательно - ссылкой на MSDN).